# Parse dot notation text configs to Javascript string

Tags: javascript, c#

I have an interesting challenge for the braniacs out there. I am trying to parse a collection of configurations into a valid Javascript string. It's probably easier if I explain with an example so here goes : 
This is the configuration items :

```
Dictionary<string, string> configs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
configs.Add("dxform.dataField", "Description");
configs.Add("dxform.label.location", "left");
configs.Add("dxform.label.text", "Action Description");
configs.Add("dxform.validationRules.[0].type", "required");
configs.Add("dxform.validationRules.[0].message", "Action Description is required");
configs.Add("dxform.validationRules.[1].type", "stringLength");
configs.Add("dxform.validationRules.[1].min", "5");
configs.Add("dxform.validationRules.[1].max", "20");
configs.Add("dxform.validationRules.[1].message", "Description must be between 5 and 20 characters");
```

And what I would like to do is parse the above collection into the following snippet of javascript :

```
{
    dataField : 'Description',
    label: {
        location: 'left',
        text:'Action Description'
    },
    validationRules:[
            {
                type:'required',
                message: 'Action Description is required'
            },
            {
                type:'stringLength',
                min:'5',
                max:'20',
                message: 'Description must be between 5 and 20 characters'
            }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, I am using dot notation to infer nesting of the javascript options, as well as "[]" to infer if its an array or not, as well as the sequence in the array. My first stab at solving this issue was through recursion, but in doing so was wondering if there is not a more intuitive way of achieving this. The config syntax is my own design and can be altered if need be. I just really need to achieve a means of representing a complex, endlessly nested javascript snippet in a key/value data table.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Where are the configs coming from? Why not just create/store it as JSON? You could use JSON.NET.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli - the configs are being stored in a database that has a key/value structure and are being populated from a more "user friendly" screen. It needs to be future-proof, hence the overly generic impl

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "future-proof". JSON is just plain text. Why store it in some custom format? If you need to transform the JSON later on to something else, that's easily done.

Comment: I agree with @EvanTrimboli - just store the JSON string in the config file in the first place. No need to first encode it to then decode it later